# Addressing two cities in the same country

Tags: grammaticality, descriptive-grammar

Should I use "In 1347, the port cities of Messina and Genoa, Italy..." or "In 1347, the port cities of Messina, Italy and Genoa, Italy..."? just want to know if one is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Neither is *grammatically* incorrect, but it seems to be a particularly American trait and (as you've found) infelicitous. Why not use "In 1347, the Italian port cities of Messina and Genoa..."? Of course, "Italy" didn't actually exist in 1347, so you could conceivably leave the reference out entirely.

Comment: Paris, France. Rome, Iddly.

Comment: You could also say *In 1347 Italy, the port cities of Messina and Genoa . . .* The date can be used as an adjective to modify the country.